# Exception Type: DoesNotExist | Profile matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to get the username in the URL pattern instead of id `<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'UserApp:profile' username=profile.username%}">Profile</a>` and so getting an error in the logout function: Profile matching query does not exist. But the profile template is rendering will all the query without any error. If I use id in the URL as well everything is working fine! Please suggest to me how can I get rid of the error. Thank you!

**Views.py**

```
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect("index")


@login_required
def profile(request, username):
    title = 'Profile'
    context={'title': title}
    profile = Profile.objects.get(username=username)
    if profile:
        context.update(profile = profile)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("user is not found")
    return render(request, 'UserApp/profile.html', context)
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from UserApp import views

app_name = 'UserApp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:username>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('update/', views.update_profile, name='update'),
]
```

**I used BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser for user registration and customer profile models to get the username**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=264, null=True, blank=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=264, blank=True)
    address_1 = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    pro_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=None, blank=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def is_fully_filled(self):
        fields_names = [f.name for f in self._meta.get_fields()]

        for field_name in fields_names:
            value = getattr(self, field_name)
            if value is None or value == '':
                return False
        return True
```

**Error in the terminal**

```
  File "C:\Users\SONJOY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SONJOY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\TrackingSystem\UserApp\views.py", line 49, in profile
    profile = Profile.objects.get(username=username)
  File "C:\Users\SONJOY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SONJOY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 429, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
UserApp.models.Profile.DoesNotExist: Profile matching query does not exist.
[15/Apr/2021 09:52:47] "GET /user/logout/ HTTP/1.1" 500 77227
```

Comment: Can you confirm the value of profile.username please? Also the value of username in the view on L49, in profile()

Comment: I fixed that and the above answer helped me to solved ll the things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you visit the `/logout` url, it will match the `profile` view, since that is the first url pattern that matches. You should put that last, such that the `signup`, `login`, `logout`, etc. view are first matched, and only if these fail, you "fire" the `profile` view, so:

```
from django.urls import path
from UserApp import views

app_name = 'UserApp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    path('update/', views.update_profile, name='update'),    
    # put this last ↓
    path('<str:username>/', views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

Comment: Better yet add  a prefix or suffix to the url pattern: `user/<str:username>/`. This makes your urls more informative, prevents such situations, generally better.

Comment: Thank you for your help and sorry for the delay. Your solution is working fine and I did not face any issue yet.. following this trick.